# What is the difference between if and cond?

Tags: hy

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

In Hy, `if*` can take (after the `if*` symbol)

- one **predicate** (evaluation returned if there are no further expressions)
- zero or one **consequent** (evaluated and returned if the predicate is **truthy**)
- (if a consequent exists) zero or one **alternative** (evaluated and returned if the predicate is **falsy**)

If the predicate is falsy and no alternative expression is supplied, None is returned.

`if` (with no star) can handle any number of pairs of predicates and consequents, with a final, optional non-predicate expression being evaluated and returned if no predicates evaluate as truthy.

How is this different to `cond`, except for `cond`'s need for brackets around predicate-consequent pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

As of [#2240](https://github.com/hylang/hy/pull/2240) (merged 2 Mar 2022), `if` and `cond` are somewhat different from what they used to be, and are better distinguished from each other. `if` requires exactly three arguments:

```
(if condition-form
  then-form
  else-form)
```

`cond` takes any even number of arguments and doesn't require brackets or provide implicit `do`s:

```
(cond
  condition1 then1
  condition2 then2
  condition3 then3)
```

`if*` has been removed.

## Original answer

The square brackets in `cond` provide an implicit `do`. That's it. I typically use `if` only for two-branch cases and `cond` for everything else. The existence of `if*` is really just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks, @Kodiologist!